# Input text on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, text, editing

Is it possible to allow user input text on a UIImageView, just like the text tool in painter?

I cannot find any resource on this topic?

Answer (score 5):

`UIImageView` is not designed to hold any text, but you could add a `UILabel` or `UITextField` either within it or on top / below it, depending on what you want to do.

For example, suppose you want to allow the user to edit a piece of text inside an image.  You could do something like this:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.png"];
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc]
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 20)];
textField.placeholder = @"type here";
[imageView addSubview:textField];

// You might also want to set the imageView's frame.
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

If you add a `UITextField` as a subview of a `UIImageView`, it's important to set the `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`, since it defaults to `NO` for that superview (it's usually `YES` by default in most `UIView`s).

**Addendum**

If you want the user to be able to click anywhere in the image to edit the text, here is one way to do it: subclass `UIControl` and add a `UIImageView` and a `UITextField` as subviews of it, and connect the clicking action of the `UIControl` to the `UITextField`.  Something like this (WARNING: not tested code, but it conveys the general idea):

```
@interface ImageAndTextView : UIControl {
  UIImageView* imageView;
  UITextField* textField;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView* imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField* textField;
- (void) click;
@end

@implementation ImageAndTextView
@synthesize imageView, textField;
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame_ {
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame_]) {
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.png"];
    self.imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    CGRect textFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 20);  // whatever frame you want
    self.textField = [[[UITextField alloc]
                      initWithFrame:textFrame] autorelease];
    [self addSubview:textField];
    // Now register an event to happen if the user clicks anywhere.
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(click)
           forEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  }
  return self;
}
- (void) click {
  [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

Comment: The function I want to implement is just like the text tool in painter:
when user touch any point of the image, a textfield shows up and waits for user text input.  How to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the current iPhone API (3.1).  You will need to create your own custom uitextfields and your own image  rendering methods to combine the layers into a captioned photo.